# Generate new variable using min/max in Stata

Tags: stata

After many years away from Stata I am currently editing code which repeatedly does something like this:

```
egen min = min(x)
egen max = max(x)
generate xn = (x - min) / (max - min)
drop min max
```

I want to reduce this code to one line. But neither of the two "natural" ways that come to my mind work.

```
gen x_index = (x - min(x)) / (max(x)- min(x))
egen x_index = (x - min(x)) / (max(x)- min(x))
```

What pieces of the Stata logic am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

The Stata functions `max()` and `min()` require two or more arguments and operate rowwise (across observations)  if given a variable as any one of the arguments. Documented at e.g. `help max()`.

The `egen` functions `max()` and `min()` can only be used within `egen` calls. They could be applied with single variables, but their use to calculate single maxima or minima is grossly inefficient unless exceptionally it is essential to store the single result in a variable. Documented except for the warnings at `help egen`.

Neither approach you consider will work without becoming more roundabout. Consider

```
su x, meanonly 
gen x_index = (x - r(min)) / (r(max)- r(min))
```

In some circumstances it might be more efficient to calculate the range just once:

```
su x, meanonly 
scalar range = r(max) - r(min) 
gen x_index = (x - r(min)) / range
```

In a program it would usually be better to give the scalar a temporary name.

Within `egen` calls, an `egen` function can be called only once.

Comment: Thanks, atm I am more concerned with readability than efficiency. Would it be equilvalent if I replaced `su x, meanonly` with `qui su x`?

Comment: No; that's not equivalent. This is easily deducible from`help summarize`. `summarize` does more than `summarize, meanonly`.

Comment: I mean equivalent **for our purpose here** to call r() afterwards.

Comment: That's correct in that you get `r(max)` and `r(min)` either way. But there is no good for preferring your version (except minutely that the option name `meanonly` could be misunderstood. Further discussion at http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0135